# How to convert json objects to json array in flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

This is my json response data. I would like to display this data in listview using map but i dont know how to convert the objects of objects to array of data.

```
  {
        "success": true,
        "data": {
            "addresses": {
                "abc": {
                    "address_id": "121",
                    "firstname": "Demo",
                    "lastname": "User",
                    "company": "Demo Company name",
                    "telephone": "1-541-754-3011",
                    "address_1": "Demo",
                    "address_2": "test address",
                    "postcode": "3333",
                    "city": "Berlin",
                    "zone_id": "1256",
                    "zone": "Berlin",
                    "zone_code": "BER",
                    "country_id": "81",
                    "country": "Germany",
                    "longitude": "",
                    "lattitude": "",
                    "iso_code_2": "DE",
                    "iso_code_3": "DEU",
                    "address_format": "{company}\r\n{firstname} {lastname}\r\n{address_1}\r\n{address_2}\r\n{postcode} {city}\r\n{country}",
                    "custom_field": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you want show in list ?

Comment: addresses of the user,if we add the new address it will add under addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to display dynamic keys (eg: `abc`) inside `addresses` object. For this, you need to iterate through `addresses` object for keys and values.

```
//json you provide
addresses = json["data"]["addresses"];
addresses.forEach((final String key, final value) {
       //here key will be abc & value will be json object
       //you can add key or value to a different list and use for list rendering later
});
```

Comment: if add another address than the data was added under address will be like this
 "xyz" :{},klm:{}

Comment: On that case, you will have abc, xyz & klm on key inside addresses.foreach.

Comment: yes the data will be
{
        "success": true,
        "data": {
            "addresses": {
                "abc": {"data"},xyz:{"data},}}}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON to dart tool](https://app.quicktype.io/), which is available online for free.

Paste your JSON to left panel and select dart language from upper right corner,

You will get your dart class code, in which you can use methods like .toMap() and .toJson(),

This can be very helpful for huge JSON data.

Comment: yes but my problem was how to convert the objects to array and assagin to a listview

Comment: Okay, sorry for confusion, after you convert your JSON into dart object (This tool also will provide you list of Objects) you can use that dart object in ListView.


You can use ListView.Builder for ListView.